# How do i get form inputs to controller using @RequestParam Annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to get user inputs from form on a Spring Boot application. What do I need to do?

I implement a login controller uses a `@RequestParam` annotation to request the data for validation but getting a result that parameter is not present.

```
// LoginController.java

@PostMapping(path = "/login")
public String userLogin(@RequestParam("email") String email, 
    @RequestParam("password") String password) {

    // validate username and password
    User user = userRepository.findUserByEmail(email);
    System.out.println(user.getEmail()+" "+user.getPassword());
    if(!(user.getEmail()==email) || !(user.getPassword()==password)){
        logger.info("Invalid user details or not register");
        return "login failed";
    }

    try{
        loginService.login(email, password);
        logger.info("User successfully login");
        return "redirect:dashboard/profile";
    }catch (Exception ex){
        logger.info("",ex);
    }
    return "Successfully logged in ..";
}
```

Login.html

```
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <form:hidden path/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required="required">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="" required="required">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
            </label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I expect the user email and password before he can login but get

> 2019-07-27 20:30:54.393  WARN 2900 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
>   [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException:
>   Required String parameter 'email' is not present]

Comment: Include code on where you are calling the the API

Comment: why are you submitting form values as param? you can simply submit as a form in `requestBody` and bind data in a POJO to use later.

Comment: Enable debug logging and check the URLs that get called and resolved. Also are you really submitting a form or are you also using a JavaScript framework to handle the actual form submit?

Answer (score -1):

You must send the paramater name from front end :

```
   const payload: FormData = new FormData();
   payload.append("email", emai);
   payload.append("password", password);
```

Comment: Doing a form submit doesn't require this.

Answer (score -1):

The issue because of bad API design and RequestParam mismatch in your URL.

Change your API to this:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/login") public String userLogin(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> user) {
          String username=user.get("user").toString();
          String password=user.get("password").toString();
}
```

And your request body JSON should be like this.

```
{
"user":"USER",
"password":"pass5&234rf"
}
```

This is the JSON payload(body) for the POST request from the client side.

Comment: Sending a simple form doesn't require a JSON payload and there is nothing wrong with sending those as parameter. Not everything needs JSON.

Comment: He was sending username and password that's not safer side. That's why I suggest him post request with payload.

Comment: Which isn't safer, you can still read the body. Next to that it wasn't the question he asked about a form submit not about changing that into a javascript thing and do a JSON post.

Comment: thank you guys, it really helpful. just that have move ahead to do other things. will look into it

Comment: thank you guys, it really helpful. just that have move ahead to do other things. will look into it